# PHP-PDO try/catch inserting dynamic html link

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, try-catch, prepared-statement

it seems i have run into a slight problem in my first shot at using PDO and prepared statements. Basically I am working on a profile page which includes an Inbox. I am using try/catch to produce the inbox:

```
<?php
$sqlin = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM message WHERE recipientID = (SELECT id FROM members WHERE username = '$pageowner')");
try {
    while($row = $sqlin->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    ?>
    <br><a href="inbox.php?id=<?php echo $row['idmessage'] ?>"><?php echo $row['title'] ?></a>
    <?php 
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    die ($e->getMessage()); 
}
?>
```

So this is supposed to relate the user id to the recipient id, and then create links to the messages. When I run in browser no links are listed

Is this an issue within my try/catch syntax? maybe stopping the php and inserting the html?--I tried echoing out but ran into problems creating that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to start to try/catch the exception before the `prepare()` and after it. And please use prepared statement, with `prepare()` method. Otherwise, you are defeating the purpuse of PDO by directly placing your variables inside the query. Which does not make your script safer from mysql injection.

```
$pageOwner = 'some external data';
try {
   $sqlin = $db->prepare("
        SELECT * FROM message 
        WHERE recipientID = (
             SELECT id
             FROM members 
             WHERE username = ?
             ) 
        ");

    $sqlin->execute(array($pageOwner)); 

     }catch(PDOException $e){
        die ($e->getMessage()); 
     }

     while($row = $sqlin->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
?>

<br><a href="inbox.php?id=<?= $row['idmessage'] ?>"><?= $row['title'] ?></a>

<?php  } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

first, **you shouldn't use try..catch here at all.**

Instead, you have to call execute() and use prepared statements. 
Also you have to separate your SQL from HTML.
Here is the proper code.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT m.* FROM message m, members mm WHERE recipientID = mm.id and username = ?";
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute([$pageowner]);
$data = $stm->fetchAll();
?>
<?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
    <br><a href="inbox.php?id=<?=$row['idmessage'] ?>"><?=$row['title'] ?></a>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Your implementation is wrong. `fetchAll()` returns multi-dimentional array so, `foreach($data as $row) $row[].. ` won't be able to extract the result. And, I don't see any reason, as to why OP should not use `try/catch`